# How to remove only text with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Some plugins come like this text after load dom:

```
<text x="1080" text-anchor="end" zIndex="8" style="cursor:pointer;color:#909090;font-size:9px;fill:#909090;" y="395">test.com</text>
```

I want to remove test.com  in text tag.How can we do this with jquery?

Comment: What's a `<text>` tag?

Comment: A quick google search couldn't give you this answer?

Comment: `.empty()`, `.text('')`, `.html('')`. Did you do *any* research?

Comment: I tried to $('text').contains('test.com').remove();  but it cant help me

Answer (score 1):

Use [`html('')`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method in jQuery

```
$('text').html('');
```

Also you can use [`text('')`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

If you want to remove only ***test.com*** then use

```
$('text').html(function(v){return v.replace('test.com','','g');});
```

Comment: Just macke sure you are selecting only the `text` you want to modify

Comment: The [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method would work just as well here. Pointing out the differences may be helpful, since it would depend on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation and if you add more `HTML` tags inside `<text>`. If so use

```
$('text').text('');
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/0k928krv/.

Comment: `.text()` without an argument simply returns the existing text. `.text('')` (empty string argument) will replace the text contents with nothing.